# AD Azure too many objects

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365

I setup my first Azure AD Connect sync but had too many OUs Selected.  I reran it,   selecting just one OU and I expected that all the other objects would be removed from Azure. It has been 2 days and those objects still show and I cannot clean them up.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD Connect has a feature about preventing accidental deletions, and this feature is enabled by default to avoid an entire OU to be deleted by accident. If your deletion is desired, use this cmd to disable this feature: Disable-ADSyncExportDeletionThreshold. More information is available https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnectsync-feature-prevent-accidental-deletes/.